# QT installation hangs on 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation, qt

The QT installation hangs on 16.04. I followed the directions here:

https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

I run the script ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.2.run

It opens a window, runs and then seems to hang. Is there a way around this problem (is it a known issue)?

[image]

---

Comment: Use the latest ubuntu, it already contains it: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/qt5-default

Comment: So I just apt-get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was the command line below. That said, it is annoying when the vendor supplied version is completely useless (QT).

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Thanks @Ipor Sircer, the user who gave the pointer.